# nsbutton click is not calling the action method - cocoa programming with swift

Tags: swift, macos, cocoa, action, nsbutton

I am facing a weird problem, i have created a subclass of NSWindowController along with the xib (Swift). In the newly created xib (window)i have added two labels, two text fields and a button, outlets for the textfields have been created and an action is also been created for the button. When i run the code and click the button, the action is not getting called. I have checked the files owner and connections everything is fine and connected. Same thing i have done with Objective C, its working perfectly fine. I don't know what went wrong.

Comment: On your storyboard, right click on the button, see if there's multiple connections. if there are, delete one of them.

Comment: Is anything logged to the console?

Comment: @Kelvin, I am using xib and there are no multiple connections.

Comment: @Willeke, nothing is logged in the console.

Comment: Is it possible to isolate the issue in a small test project?

Comment: I am getting this message in the console - "Demo-CocoaSwift[2676:477984] [default] Unable to load Info.plist exceptions (eGPUOverrides)"

Comment: Can you share the screenshot of the xib file and the button's actions (right click on the button)

Answer (score 3):

I faced the same problem. I added a strong reference in the .h file to the sub window controller (aka `NSWindowController`) declared in the main window controller and the problem is solved.

Put something like

`@property (strong, nonatomic) AboutWindowController *aboutWindowController;`

between `@interface` and `@end` in your header file.

Then in your implementation (.m) file, invoke your second window by:

```
self.aboutWindowController = [[AboutWindowController alloc] initWithWindowNibName:@"AboutWindow"];
    [self.aboutWindowController showWindow:self];
```

Replace `aboutWindowController` with your own controller's variable. Replace `AboutWindowController` with your window controller subclass name.

You just need a strong reference from the main window for the second window to work properly.